# ODBC Api SQLMoreResults falls over when called if Stored Proc does updates or select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, odbc

I am coding in VB.NET and have the following test stored procedure in my SQL DB.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ACOCMP1.test1 (@a numeric(28,0) output, @b numeric(28,0), @c numeric(28,0), @d numeric(28,0), @e numeric(28,0))
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE ACOCMP1.TB1 SET TRANREF = TRANREF + 1
    SELECT @a = TRANREF FROM ACOCMP1.TB1 
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    RETURN (@a + @b + @c + @d + @e)
GO
```

I have called **SQLAllocHandle** and **SQLBindParameter** to bind the output and *@a*

```
sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLAllocHandle(SQLAllocHandle.SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbinf.hdbcv, hstmt)
retValPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8)
sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLBindParameter64(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQLCDataTypes.SQL_C_DOUBLE, SQLDataTypes.SQL_FLOAT, 8, 0, retValPtr, 8, NULL_POINTER)
retArgsPtr(0) = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8)
sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLBindParameter64(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQLCDataTypes.SQL_C_DOUBLE, SQLDataTypes.SQL_FLOAT, 8, 0, retArgsPtr(0), BUFSIZE, NULL_POINTER)
```

The sql is then *"{?=call acocmp1.test1 (?,2,3,4,5)}"*

And then:

```
Dim sqlStr As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(sql)
sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLExecDirect(hstmt, sqlStr, sqlStr.Length)
```

If I try copying with Marshal before I call **SQLMoreResults** I get random data (undertsandable right) however whenever I do call **SQLMoreResults** the program crashes, however If I call it in the *watch* window it does not fall over, returns 100 and from that point I can call it within my program as much as I want and the data returned by:

```
ReDim retVals(0)
Marshal.Copy(retValPtr, retVals, 0, 1)
```

Is then meaningfull. I am connecting with a 64-bit odbc and 64-bit project. It works fine with a 32-bit odbc (with a 32-bit odbc). Here is the declaration for the dll calls:

```
#Region "SQLBindParameter"
#Region "x64"
    <DllImport("ODBC32.DLL", EntryPoint:="SQLBindParameter", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Winapi)> _
    Public Shared Function SQLBindParameter64(ByVal StatementHandle As Integer, ByVal ParameterNumber As UShort, ByVal InputOutputType As Short, ByVal ValueType As SQLCDataTypes, ByVal ParameterType As Short, ByVal ColumnSize As ULong, ByVal DecimalDigits As Short, ByVal ParameterValuePtr As IntPtr, ByVal BufferLength As Long, ByRef StrLen_or_IndPtr As Long) As Short
        ' Leave the body of the function empty.
    End Function
#End Region
#Region "x86"
    <DllImport("ODBC32.DLL", EntryPoint:="SQLBindParameter", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Winapi)> _
    Public Shared Function SQLBindParameter32(ByVal StatementHandle As Integer, ByVal ParameterNumber As UShort, ByVal InputOutputType As Short, ByVal ValueType As SQLCDataTypes, ByVal ParameterType As Short, ByVal ColumnSize As UInteger, ByVal DecimalDigits As Short, ByRef ParameterValuePtr As Double, ByVal BufferLength As Integer, ByVal StrLen_or_IndPtr As Integer) As Short
        ' Leave the body of the function empty.
    End Function
#End Region
#End Region
```

Any ideas why this falls over would be great.

Adding more code:

```
dbinf.host_bdouble = 6 (SQLDataTypes.SQL_FLOAT)

Public Function callMasterFunction(ByVal functionName As String, ByVal numReturn As Short, ByVal ArgumentsAsString As String, ParamArray Arguments() As Object) As Decimal
        Dim sqlReturn As Short = 0
        Dim hstmt As Integer = 0
        Dim retArgsPtr() As IntPtr
        Dim retValPtr As IntPtr
        Try
            ChkPrf(functionName)
            sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLAllocHandle(SQLAllocHandle.SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbinf.hdbcv, hstmt)
            If sqlReturn <> SQL_SUCCESS And sqlReturn <> SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO Then
                Throw New Exception(GetdberrorEx(dbinf.henv, dbinf.hdbcv, sqlReturn, hstmt, pvErrorNumber))
            End If

            Const BUFSIZE As Integer = 8
            Dim retVal As Double = 0
            If IsWin64() Then
                retValPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(BUFSIZE)
                sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLBindParameter64(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQLCDataTypes.SQL_C_DOUBLE, dbinf.host_bdouble, BUFSIZE, 0, retValPtr, BUFSIZE, NULL_POINTER)
            Else
                sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLBindParameter32(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQLCDataTypes.SQL_C_DOUBLE, dbinf.host_bdouble, BUFSIZE, 0, retVal, BUFSIZE, NULL_POINTER)
            End If
            If sqlReturn <> SQL_SUCCESS And sqlReturn <> SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO Then
                Throw New Exception(GetdberrorEx(dbinf.henv, dbinf.hdbcv, sqlReturn, hstmt, pvErrorNumber))
            End If

            Dim retVals() As Double
            If numReturn > 0 Then
                If IsWin64() Then
                    ReDim retArgsPtr(numReturn - 1)
                Else
                    ReDim retVals(numReturn - 1)
                End If
                For i As UShort = 0 To numReturn - 1
                    If IsWin64() Then
                        retArgsPtr(i) = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(BUFSIZE)
                        sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLBindParameter64(hstmt, i + 2, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQLCDataTypes.SQL_C_DOUBLE, dbinf.host_bdouble, BUFSIZE, 0, retArgsPtr(i), BUFSIZE, NULL_POINTER)
                    Else
                        sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLBindParameter32(hstmt, i + 2, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQLCDataTypes.SQL_C_DOUBLE, dbinf.host_bdouble, BUFSIZE, 0, retVals(i), BUFSIZE, NULL_POINTER)
                    End If
                    If sqlReturn <> SQL_SUCCESS And sqlReturn <> SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO Then
                        Throw New Exception(GetdberrorEx(dbinf.henv, dbinf.hdbcv, sqlReturn, hstmt, pvErrorNumber))
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            Dim sql As String = "{?=call " & functionName
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ArgumentsAsString) And (Arguments IsNot Nothing AndAlso (Arguments.Length = 0)) Then
                sql &= "}"
            Else
                sql &= "("
                If numReturn > 0 Then
                    For i As Short = 0 To numReturn - 1
                        sql &= "?,"
                    Next
                End If
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ArgumentsAsString) Then
                    sql &= ArgumentsAsString
                ElseIf Arguments IsNot Nothing AndAlso (Arguments.Length > numReturn) Then
                    For i As Short = numReturn To Arguments.Length - 1
                        Select Case VarType(Arguments(i))
                            Case VariantType.Null
                                sql &= "NULL,"
                            Case VariantType.Short, VariantType.Integer, VariantType.Single, VariantType.Double, VariantType.Decimal
                                sql &= VB6.Format(Arguments(i)) & ","
                            Case VariantType.Date
                                sql &= Fdatetime(Arguments(i)) & ","
                            Case Else
                                sql &= fnds(CStr(Arguments(i))) & ","
                        End Select
                    Next
                End If
                If sql.EndsWith(",") Then
                    sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.LastIndexOf(","))
                End If
                sql = sql & ")}"
            End If

            Dim sqlStr As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(sql)
            sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLExecDirect(hstmt, sqlStr, sqlStr.Length)
            If sqlReturn <> SQL_SUCCESS And sqlReturn <> SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO And sqlReturn <> SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND Then
                Throw New Exception(GetdberrorEx(dbinf.henv, dbinf.hdbcv, sqlReturn, hstmt, pvErrorNumber))
            End If

            Try

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            Dim more As Object = SQLMoreResults(hstmt)
            If more <> SQL_SUCCESS And more <> SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO And more <> SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND Then
                Throw New Exception(GetdberrorEx(dbinf.henv, dbinf.hdbcv, more, hstmt, pvErrorNumber))
            End If
            Do While more <> SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND
                more = SQLMoreResults(hstmt)
                If more <> SQL_SUCCESS And more <> SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO And more <> SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND Then
                    Throw New Exception(GetdberrorEx(dbinf.henv, dbinf.hdbcv, more, hstmt, pvErrorNumber))
                End If
            Loop

            If IsWin64() Then
                ReDim retVals(0)
                Marshal.Copy(retValPtr, retVals, 0, 1)
                retVal = retVals(0)
                If numReturn > 0 Then
                    For i As Integer = 0 To numReturn - 1
                        Marshal.Copy(retArgsPtr(i), retVals, 0, 1)
                        Arguments(i) = retVals(0)
                    Next
                End If
            ElseIf retVals IsNot Nothing AndAlso retVals.Length > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To numReturn - 1
                    Arguments(i) = retVals(i)
                Next
            End If

            Return retVal
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            If hstmt > 0 Then
                sqlReturn = DB_ODBC_3X.SQLFreeHandle(SQLAllocHandle.SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt)
                If sqlReturn <> SQL_SUCCESS And sqlReturn <> SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO And sqlReturn <> SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND Then
                    Throw New Exception(GetdberrorEx(dbinf.henv, dbinf.hdbcv, sqlReturn, hstmt, pvErrorNumber))
                End If
            End If
            If IsWin64() Then
                If retValPtr <> 0 Then
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(retValPtr)
                End If
                If retArgsPtr IsNot Nothing AndAlso retArgsPtr.Length > 0 Then
                    For i As Integer = 0 To numReturn - 1
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(retArgsPtr(i))
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Is your program 32 or 64bit?

Comment: The project is compiled as Any CPU, but the startup project is 64-bit.

Comment: I dont get what you mean with "I am connecting with a 64-bit odbc" and then "It works fine in 32bit": Does your program work if you compile it as 32bit app and then run it, but crashes as 64bit?

Comment: Sorry. We currently run in 32bit odbc and 32bit software (all projects except for teh startup are compiles as any cpu and then we compile the startup as 32 bit). when I run the code above it works fine. I then change the startup project to be 64bit and compile then change delete the odbc connection and re create as a 64bit connection (using the windows build in odbc data source administrator). Then when I run the program it crashes when calling SQLMoreResults

Comment: As you say that the app crashes while doing SQLMoreResults(), but only on 64bit, I'm guessing that one of your buffers is too small and the ODBC lib tries to write past the end of a buffer you pass in in SQLBindColumns. Is `BUFSIZE` defined to something different on x64 compared to x86?

Comment: `BUFSIZE` is set to 8. From what I have read a double is 8 bytes and I return a double.

Comment: As a test, can you try: Does it crash if you do not bind any output columns? Does it crash if you bind only one of the return values (and modify the statement accordingly, having only one question mark in it). And then try only the other one.

Comment: I will try that now. I have tried the same stored proc only without the update and select. (Set @a = someting) and that works fine. But I think you may be on to something with teh buffer overflow as every now and the visual studio is showing me a symbol loading skipped page with a stackoverflowexception error. I will tery increasing the size of the buffer now.

Comment: Increasing the size of the buffer does not break my code however it still falls over when I call SQLMoreResults(). But what is strange is if I put a break point on the call to stop it then add the call to the watch list tab and run it there it works fine. and i can call it fine in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have found my answer for now. When the SP is updating, deleting, inserting and it has row count info my code falls over (ecxept if I run it in the debug watch window in visual studio, not sure why this is). However as we do not use the rowcount info I will simply add set nocount on at the start of each SP and this allows it to run. If someone could answer why this is that would be great, otherwise untill next time....